# JQuery fadeOut fadeIn problems when changing the selected element

Tags: jquery, fadein, fadeout

I am attempting to fade out the contents of a container, then replace with some new html and fade them back in. **Note: The container will always contain at least one child div*

Here is my code:

```
$("#identifier div:first").fadeOut(300,function(){
  $(this).parent().html("<div> some new element </div>");
}).fadeIn(300);
```

I have tried a few different methods, and no luck. The new elements appear, but without the sought after fade effect.

*the one i posted seemed to be the clearest.. the rest were long shots at best*

I assume that this probably isn't the correct method to do such a task, however it is all I can think of. Any direction would be appreciated.

Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
$("#identifier div:first").fadeOut(300,function(){
  $(this).parent().html("<div> some new element </div>")
  $(this).fadeIn(300);
});
```

Comment: Tried this with one of my first attempts. didn't end up working.

Comment: Using the fiddle Stack provided i have altered it to http://jsfiddle.net/hnVaF/13/  still no luck, I also attempted your new update. The fade in effect is still lost.

Comment: @rlemon - I think this is perfect take a look at this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/hnVaF/14/

Comment: @rlemon - Did you get a chance to take a look at this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/hnVaF/14/ ?

Comment: Here is the implementation : http://rlemon.zzl.org/index.php
Everything works fine on my local server, but as soon as i upload it things stop fading nicely.. strange. hopefully it is only a problem with the free php host i'm using to post a public example.

Comment: May be the due to the free host.

Answer (score 2):

Try this :

```
   $('#identifier').children().first().fadeOut(300,function(){

       $(this).html("Some new element");

   }).fadeIn(300);
```

**Demo :**

http://jsfiddle.net/hnVaF/